# insert one to many code first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want insert factor in db and any factor have customer Id.

i have two class

```
public class Customer
    {

        [Key, ForeignKey("Factor")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Factor> Factor { get; set; }

    }

    public class Factor
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FactorDetails> FactorDetails { get; set; }

        public virtual FactorType FactorType { get; set; }

    }
```

and i create modelview for these two classes,

```
public class CreateFactorViewModel
{
    public Factor Factor { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

in create view i add new factor and select one customer from dropdown list.
in create controller i want add CustomerId to factor customer Id

```
    public ActionResult Create(CreateFactorViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Factor.Customer = new Customer { Id = model.CustomerId };

             db.Factors.Add(model.Factor);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

but i get this error

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

i know this error occurred from customer attribute,but i don't know
how i can inset factor base customer Id.

can you help me?

Comment: You did not provide the name value .as name is required

Comment: yes,i konw,but i dont konw,this scenario is correct or not?

Comment: no anybody can answer my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from user question,
you should declare a ForeignKey

change the class from this code

```
    public class Factor
    {
        ...
        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public int Customer_Id { get; set; }
        ...
}

  public ActionResult Create(CreateFactorViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             model.Factor.Customer_Id = model.CustomerId;

             db.Factors.Add(model.Factor);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your by your own

```
try
{
 db.SaveChanges(); //put your DbContext here
}
 catch (Exception exception)
 {
   var sss = exception; //Put a break point here
 }
```

now analysis on exception .You will find your problem by inspecting **InnerExcetion** most of the case